# What else I should do to configure my router so one router is the main router and the other is an access point?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I had an connection FTTH (fiber-to-the-home) and I was not very satisfied with it was using Point-to-Point Protocol over Ethernet.

I have an  Optical Network Unit and router (came with connection) says 1 and additional router (Archer a6) name it 2.

My router 2 was connected to router 1 via ethernet cable and I was able to access internet from both.

But my new ISP gave me an static IP address with default gateway so the thing is my (Optical Network Unit and router) 1 is only acting as Optical Network Unit and I am only able to access Internet from router 2, even after setting same configuration in router 1. Router 2 still connected to router 1.

This was all the settings he told me do in my router 2.

> [image: image showing router 2 settings]

I did the same setting in router 1.

> [image: router 2 settings]

So in the status it show the connection is up and IP address and all.

> [image: status]

But I still do not get access to internet from router 1. What I want to do is have the proper connection setup in router 1 and use router2 as access point.

Comment: I haven't absorbed everything from your question and I never used an ONU.. But thought i'd point out the following.. maybe some "routers" aren't built to be just Wireless Access Points.. Also,  TP-Link do make a device that is built to be a Wireless Access Point.. I have one, it's a https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01LRQW0GM/   I use it simply because I think its Wireless Access Point feature might be more reliable than the one on my "router".

Comment: the thing is wireless access point comes after but  first i need internet access in first router, even if i dont use the second router still i got no internet access from the first one. according to status and settings i should be able to connect to internet .

Comment: If you are telling me that even if you unplug the "router" that you want as wireless access point then you have no internet access, then you are not doing this properly at all and asking the wrong question. You should unplug the second "router" and just try to get internet with the first "router", and don't even ask about a second device until you have internet from the first device. You are not doing basic troubleshooting if you aren't doing that and it looks like you aren't.

Comment: i have tried unplugging the second router , still the result is same

Comment: You aren't understanding what i'm saying.   I'm saying this whole question is the wrong question

Comment: i get what you saying this question is kind of wrong , but still question + comments kind of summarize the problem.

Comment: This isn't simply a help site, it's a site with a database of questions and answers, for people to look up.. it's not just about helping the person that asked the question it's about helping anybody with that question. A badly written question is not good for the site

Answer (score 0):

First, if you have just one IP address, then **only one** device can have that IP address assigned at a time. It makes no sense to configure the same WAN address on two different routers.

Specifically, only the router that is **directly** connected to the ISP (through its ONU) should have the ISP-issued address configured on it.

For example, if router2 is connected to router1 then it is within router1's network, not within the ISP's network anymore, therefore it needs to get an address from router1 as well. In this case using DHCP would be fine.

Second, access points **should not** have any WAN configuration whatsoever. (Dealing with "WANs" is a router's job. Access points are bridges – they should belong to the same LAN as the actual computers/phones/other wireless devices that you intend to connect.)

So if you want Wi-Fi roaming to work automatically, search for "LAN-to-LAN connection" for your access point's model.

Comment: i think that after unplugging the router 2 i should be able to assign the IP to the router 1, and that i did. so the correction should be that the problem is just to configure the router 1 for internet , i just mentioned router 2 to tell that the setting work on different router.